# Keeping a counter with ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'd like to keep a counter of executed threads, to use in the same threads that I am executing.

The problem here is that although the counter increases, it increases unevenly and from the console output I got this (I have a for loop that executes 5 threads with ExecutorService):

```
This is a test. N:3
This is a test. N:4
This is a test. N:4
This is a test. N:4
This is a test. N:4
```

As you can see instead of getting `1,2,3,4,5` I got `3,4,4,4,4`.

I assume this is because the for loop is running fast enough to execute the threads, and the threads are fast enough to execute the code requesting for the counter faster than the counter can update itself (does that even make sense?).

Here is the code (it is smaller and there is no meaningful use for the counter):

```
for (int i = 0; i  <  5; i++)
{

Thread thread;
thread = new Thread()
    {

        public void run()
            {



                System.out.println("This is test. N: "+aldo );
                //In here there is much more stuff, saying it because it might slow down the execution (if that is the culprit?)
                return;
            }
    };

threadList.add(thread);
}
//later
for (int i = 0; i < threadList.size(); i++)
{

executor.execute(threadList.get(i));
aldo = aldo + 1;

}
executor.shutdown();
try
{
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException e)
{

}
```

Yes, `aldo` the counter ( with a few other lists, I think) are missing from the code (they are very simple).

Comment: The way you have your code does not guarantee that `aldo` wont be 3 for example by the time first thread runs. Using `AtomicInteger` wont help here either.

Comment: @tsolakp, What can I do then?

Comment: You can pass `aldo` to each thread but you still will have problem printing them in order. The biggest question here is "why you need them printed in order and do you actually need to use threads in here".

Comment: I am trying to make some sort of program that can handle much more threads than those 5. Unfortunately for cleanup I need a way to identify which is which, and as such I need a counter.

Comment: Then you probably dont need the ordering and can just pass `aldo` to each thread in the loop. This way each thread will have its unique value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I know of doing this is by creating a custom thread class with a constructor that passes in a number. The variable holding the number can then be used later for any needed logging. Here is the code I came up with.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class NumberedThread implements Runnable {
        private final int number;
        public NumberedThread(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("This is test. N: " + number);
        }
    }

    List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i  <  6; i++) threadList.add(new Thread(new NumberedThread(i)));

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);;
    for (Thread thread : threadList) executor.execute(thread);
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
}
```

You could also use a string object instead if you wanted to name the threads.

Comment: No problem glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

`aldo` is not modified by the tasks in the thread, but instead is modified in the main thread, here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadList.size(); i++) {
    executor.execute(threadList.get(i));
    //here...
    aldo = aldo + 1;
}
```

Also, since you want a counter that can increase its value in several threads, then you may use an `AtomicInteger` rather than `int`.

Your code should look like this:

```
AtomicInteger aldo = new AtomicInteger(1);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    executor.execute( () -> {
        System.out.println("This is test. N: " + aldo.getAndIncrement());
    });
}
```

Comment: This surely does it's job but the problem still remains. I now got `3,4,4,3,5`, instead of `1,2,3,4,5`.